# Additional image only sitemap

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, google-analytics, sitemaps

My main sitemap is created automatically and the images are hard to find on the site so I created a separate image sitemap

As you can see below the image sitemap shows that the were submitted properly and shows that 20 web pages were submitted.

I know for a fact that those 20 web pages are already submitted and indexed due to the main sitemap.xml

Will I run into problems with this second image sitemap submitting pages that are already indexed?

[image]